# How to find out what activity activated a favorite?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, user-interface, bookmarks

I have several favorite questions and it is a great feature that every time something happens around them, they are flagged up for me. However, when I turn to them, in most cases I cannot figure out what has been added (or removed, for that matter), or changed in any other way.

Well, you may respond: just read it over carefully and be content with any new information that you will obtain. But maybe there is a way to detect the change that caused activation of the favorite which I am not aware of - say, some logs I could see, etc.

And in case there is no such thing - does anybody agree that it would be good to have a way to see the activity that caused flagging of the favorite?

Comment: If a question has been modified or received an answer, you can click on the field which states something like "Active  N days ago" (to the right side of the question) and be directed to the position of the latest activity. See, for example, the top right of this page: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/189106/is-any-connected-fibre-of-a-fibration-of-a-sphere-also-a-sphere  Alternatively, you can always visit the timeline page for the thread: https://mathoverflow.net/posts/189106/timeline

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You went to "favorites" tab. Now (not necessary, but just to see what post was last active) select "Activity" and then click the date (sssssh, it is the secret, for this reason the timestamp looks unclickable ;) ).

> [image: just favorites tab]

If you are taken to the question, then something was happened to the question. Go to the revisions (if no "edited X time ago" displayed, then go to find the revisions, go to `/posts/{question-id}/revisions`, where question id is the number after the `/questions/` in your address bar). If the last action in the revisions occurred on the day which is shown in your favorites, everything is ok - now you know what made this question active (**bounty** or **edit**).

But if the timestamp of the last action in the revisions doesn't match the timestamp in your favorites, then this question was **poked by [Community ♦](https://mathoverflow.net/users/-1/community)** or, if you have less than 10k, an answer was posted and then deleted, or deleted answer was edited.

If you are taken to the answer and don't see "edited X time ago", the last activity was when this **answer was posted**. But if you see "edited X time ago", then the last activity was an **edit occurred to this answer**.

Comment: Thank you and @RicardoAndrade for the explications. Well I have no idea why ssssssh but... :)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე ***;)***

Answer (score 1):

I first check when the question was last edited.

Then I check the latest answers -- at the beginning of answers there are three tabs: |Active| |Oldest| |Votes|.  Selecting |Active| puts the latest on top.