# Fake activity mark on favorites tab

Tags: support, user-interface, bookmarks

I already asked about activity on favorites ([How to find out what activity activated a favorite?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2039/41291)). This time it is about what seems to be a bug. Every now and then the favorites tab shows new activity there. When I open it and sort by activity, the newest ones are actually few days ago and I definitely remember that I already looked into them. For example, this happened just now: the tab showed two favorites with new activity; one is 15 hours ago and the next a week ago. And I cannot click on grey activity link, which also confirms that I saw these already.

(As requested by Asaf Karagila I am adding a snapshot; when I first opened the favorites tab the first two entries had reddish background)

[image]

Initially I agreed that this was a duplicate and related to automatic community bumps but now again the same favorite is marked with new activity while in fact nothing has changed from previous time at all, no activity indicated either by Community or otherwise, so I decided to disagree that it is a duplicate

Comment: Can you give an example of some post which is like that?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Added a snapshot

Comment: I see, thanks! If there is no duplicate, could you please make this an answer? I would never suspect anything like this!

Comment: No it is still very strange - right now it again shows new activity at the same favorite as before, although nothing has changed there

Comment: I am not clear what the concern is. It seems there is a new comment from about 7 hours ago on the first question, which *should* reactivate it in your favorites. I agree though that this is not a dupe of the current target. Is it possible you were not aware that comments on the question count?

Comment: While I am not sure when the activity link is clickable (I will try to find out) I do not think that "And I cannot click on grey activity link, which also confirms that I saw these already." is accurate. To see this check some others and you should be able to click it on some long inactive ones, somewhat implying that there is not direct connection there. Moreover what do you mean by "looked into them"? In any case whether or not you visited the page in some other way does not matter, if you did not check from or on the favorites tab.

Comment: @quid Thanks for pointing this out. Indeed it is only my interpretation that if that gray link is not clickable it means I've already checked this particular change. As by "looked into them" I mean that I went there through the link in my favorites list.

Comment: I have no definite information, but I tested the "link" issue a bit. It is my impression that the  activity-link is not working when it is  redundant with the link given by the title, that is in particular if there is no answer. I am not certain about the exact criteria. But it is decidedly not that one used it already that makes it go away. Thanks for the clarification with the "looked at." Back to the original problem, I continue to suspect that the activity indicated came from comments on the question.

Comment: Um yes I did not notice - the last comment there is 12 hours ago, maybe the system reacted to that. I somehow presumed that the link with the time and username indicate the modification that activated the favorite entry.

Comment: I can see that this is a natural interpretation, but it just seems not to be the case. The "activity" corresponds to the usual events that change activity for a question-thread, that is asked, answered, post edited, while favorites are activated by those events *and* comments on the question-post.

Comment: I believe it would be useful to have this information as an answer, could you please provide it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unexpected activation of the favorite question-threads is due to comments on the question post. A comment on the question-post is one of the actions that activate a favorite question-thread.

This action, adding a comment, does however not change the time-stamp of the the question-thread (unlike other actions that active a favorite, such as a new answers and edits to existing posts).

Thus, the time-stamp does not (necessarily) directly correspond to the last activating action on the post.

Finally, the (non-)click-ability of the time-stamp is unrelated to this. Rather it seems it depends on whether the link on the time-stamp is redundant with the link given by the title of the question.